# Handling a big number of Summary Statistics in ABC

Tags: bayesian, approximate-bayesian-computation

I went through a big amount of literature in $ABC$, in how it is possible to handle a large number of (many cases sufficient) summary statistics. Like a large number, I consider $K>>200$, where $K$ denotes the number of sufficient summary statistics used in $ABC$.

A such a big number of statistics $K$ can result in a small acceptance rate and really slow/bad mixing of an $MCMC$ algorithm.

A potential way that I read that can alleviate that problem is to

$1)$ Use a model selection/reduction technique to choose a significantly smaller number of sufficient summary statistics from those $K$,

$2)$ Construct a number of $M$ summary statistics where $M<<K$ and hopefully $M$ will have a decent amount of information for your data.

In my case, using the first method $1)$ I still end up with a big number of sufficient summary statistics. For example, if I have $K=200$ after use of dimensionality reduction I end up with $170$ sufficient statistics where I consider it as a really big number of statistics.

---

So, my questions can be summed up to the following, (I didn't include problem-specific details because I'm more interested if there exist the way of handling such a problems):

$i)$ In cases where we have such a large number of (sufficient) summary statistics $K=200$ or $500$ or even larger, are we doomed to have bad $ABC-MCMC$ computations because it is quite unlikely to produce data that are closely related??

$ii)$ I'm might haven't searched well, but are there any research analysis/simulations that consider such a big amount of summary statistics??

Comment: With a large number of summaries, we recommended using random forests as automatically selecting the most significant among those. Note also that our software DIYABC is able to handle hundreds of summaries.

Comment: @Xi'an Really elegant approach! I have two questions, why do you consider the prediction of the transformed parameter $\theta$? And also, if I understand correctly, we want the sampling from the prior predictive distribution to be as variable as possible, i.e. having as many different values $\tau^{t}$ as possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One promising avenue to consider is to make better proposals that are more likely to be accepted in such a way that you still get a valid Markov Chain. One of the proposals for this is Hamiltonian ABC, but see [this critical discussion](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/hamiltonian-abc/).

Another approach could be to make the simulation differentiable. That is obviously not directly possible, but if you can create a neural network that approximates your simulations well, then you would have a differentiable system. This might have to be a somewhat bespoke solution for each individual case, because you are presumably somewhat limited in how many simulations you can perform and would (probably?) have to not just simulate once for each parameter value, but repeatedly to capture the extent of variability for the same inputs. Thus, you'd want to reflect as many constraints of the real system, as possible.

Related to that idea, I saw [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.01861).